# IndexedDb sorting of singly linked list

Tags: sorting, singly-linked-list, indexeddb

I have an indexedDB store of the given elements (linked list):

```
{
    node: "9c1628e6-143c-4320-a72f-25f245e6ef06",
    uuid: "34d54192-ef73-4bbf-adda-2b83e1bb6989",
    next: "2e3d762d-e37a-4e8b-8732-197e736482c2",
    isHead: 1
}

{
    node: "9c1628e6-143c-4320-a72f-25f245e6ef06",
    uuid: "2e3d762d-e37a-4e8b-8732-197e736482c2",
    next: "366761a4-968d-4e44-b848-ef4a328f66f2",
    isHead: 0
}
... until next is null
```

Now I want all the entries for `node="9c1628e6-143c-4320-a72f-25f245e6ef06"` in the correct order.

Sorting as a post-process after fetching all entries is simple, but I wonder if there is a more efficient way by manipulating the cursor.continue parameter.

Sure, I can add a "sorting" property, but this will not be performant when inserting a new block.

Thanks for any advices or ideas in advance.

Comment: My approach would be to create another "metadata" object store and store the head and the tail uuid inside of it. And then you can iterate through your ll data structure by repeatedly making `store.get(nextKey)` requests. You could probably do the same by creating an index with the `isHead` property, but I think that is kind of wasteful.
Also, there may be a nicer way of using the `cursor` object, but I don't know if that's possible since I'm new to indexeddb as well.

Comment: The closet match I get is to fetch all by "node" index and re-sort afterwards

Comment: Hmm that could work also, that way you can reduce the number or read calls as well I suppose. But either way, I think it would help to have a `nodes` store, and store the node metadata inside there, like the head uuid.